# Doing calculations in Snowflake VS. in Java

Tags: java, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Asummed I have several not big tables (thousands of records maximum, ~10 columns), and I need to join them and do more aggregations like count and group by; what is preferred, in terms of performance: doing the joins and aggregations in Snowflake, or fetching the data as is from Snowflake and doing the joins and aggregations in Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need to further process the data in your Java code (in a way that is not possible in Snowflake) and ignoring the fact that there are a large number of unknown variables implicit in your question, then doing it all in Snowflake will almost certainly perform better - Snowflake is an engine specifically designed to process data in the way you've described; Java is a generic coding language